# How to insert data into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I've been attempting to put data into mysql with php, but i keep getting this error:

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Show, Picture, Name, Date, Poster, Text) VALUES('1','http://www.thepsychicnetwor' at line 1
```

This is my current code on my insert.php page.

http://pastebin.com/nWvrDPN7

Here Is My Form page:

http://pastebin.com/gyUdSgsz

How do i fix the error

EDIT:
This Fixes it but it still wont imput "Text"

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Posts (`Show`, Picture, Name, Date, Poster, Text) VALUES('$_POST[Show]','$_POST[Picture]','$_POST[Name]','$_POST[Date]','$_POST[Poster]','$_POST[Text]')";
```

Comment: After you get this working, I wonder how long before someone steals all of your data and deletes it. Use mysqli or PDO and prepared statements.

Comment: That has nothing to do with what I'm saying. I could steal all of your data just by visiting the site. It's called sql injection and your code is begging for it.

Comment: By the looks of your `VALUES('1'` you may be using the wrong column type. Also check if you have an AUTO_INCREMENT set to it, as well as any foreign keys set up. @user3261777 - Your code as shown in your pastebin files, should work, along with using backticks around the reserved word `SHOW`

Comment: @Fred-ii- It Wont Put "text" into the database though.

Comment: If your text contains apostrophes, quotes etc, then that could be a factor. @TheWebDev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Show` is a [reserved MySQL word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), you need to escape it using backticks as:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Posts (`Show`, Picture, Name, Date, Poster, Text) VALUES('$_POST[Show]','$_POST[Picture]','$_POST[Name]','$_POST[Date]','$_POST[Poster]','$_POST[Text]')";
```

**Update:**

As your `text` column isn't working, the only reason I can think of as already commented by @Fred-ii in your question, you might have apostrophes in the value.

One option is to use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) on your values as:

```
mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[Text])
```

Use this function on all values that may include the following characters:

> \x00, \n, \r, \, ', " and \x1a.

Please make sure to read the "Warning" on the linked [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) page when you're at it.

Comment: Thank you but for some reason "text" isn't being imputed

Comment: Are you taking about just `Text` column?  Can you provide further information on this problem?

Comment: Yes, The $_POST[Text] Is not being put into the table for some odd reason.

Comment: Please print the `$sql` and add it to your question.

Comment: Probably because your `name="comment"` should be named `name="Text"` @TheWebDev

Comment: Ok, just for the heckuvit, can you wrap all your column names with backticks and not just the reserved word `SHOW`? @TheWebDev I know that `DATE` and `TEXT` are not reserved words, however they could be playing havoc. Stranger things have happened.

Comment: @TheWebDev, I think you got confused with what I meant.  I meant the generated query not the updated code.  Also please don't link code to some external site.  Edit your question, add any required information here.

Comment: And, can you try it this way `('" . $_POST['Show'] . "','" . $_POST['Picture'] . "','" . $_POST['Name'] . "','" . $_POST['Date'] ."','" . $_POST['Poster'] . "','" . $_POST['Text'] . "')` @TheWebDev

Comment: I'm also wondering if you did reload the form after you changed the form's element from `comment` to `Text`? @TheWebDev

Comment: @TheWebDev, I'm suggesting use of `mysql_real_escape_string` on all the non-numeric valued columns at the very least.  Please see the update on this answer.

Comment: "Opening a can" as @Fred-ii- calls it :)

Comment: Exactly. The reason I didn't put in answer ;-) @vee Just like the old VCR's, too many moving parts where too many things can and will go wrong. When in doubt, PDO. I'll bet the OP's trying to enter Mr. O'Toole or something similar.

Comment: Well, this one looks like is `Dead in the Water` along with the fish that ate the whole can of "worms". @vee See you on the flip side. ;-) `+1` for your efforts, cheers.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I'm assuming `mysql_real_escape_string` solved the issue.  OP appears new to SO, so lets let the natural course of learning in using SO take over!

Comment: I agree. 9 times out of 10, when we don't hear any news from OP, is one of two things. 1) Is now working and is having the time of their life, or 2) Is completely frustrated and has resorted to just giving up and headed off to bed, crying on pillow. @vee

Answer (score 1):

You have to put single quotes on the $_POST variables.

```
$_POST['Show']
```

not

```
$_POST[Show]
```

same goes to all other variables.

Answer (score 1):

This is the SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO Posts (Show, Picture, Name, Date, Poster, Text) 
    VALUES('$_POST[Show]', '$_POST[Picture]', '$_POST[Name]', '$_POST[Date]',
           '$_POST[Poster]','$_POST[Text]');
```

The word `show` is a reserved word in MySQL.  Actually, `date` and `text` are also keywords, but not reserved.  You need backticks for `show` and should use them for `date` and `text`:

```
INSERT INTO Posts (`Show`, Picture, Name, `Date`, Poster, `Text`) 
    VALUES('$_POST[Show]', '$_POST[Picture]', '$_POST[Name]', '$_POST[Date]',
           '$_POST[Poster]','$_POST[Text]');
```

Comment: DATE and TEXT are not reserved words http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: @Fred-ii- . . . Is there something unclear about "but not reserved".  They are, however, elements of the language, representing types which MySQL has chosen as exceptions that all types are reserved.

Comment: If MySQL says they're not reserved words, then I shouldn't see why it would cause a problem. However, you and I are both or can be 50% right and 50% wrong ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query. The post variable is warped with curly brackets.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO Posts (`Show`, Picture, Name, Date, Poster, Text) VALUES('{$_POST[Show]}','{$_POST[Picture]}','{$_POST[Name]}','{$_POST[Date]}','{$_POST[Poster]}','{$_POST[Text]}')";
```

Answer (score 0):

index.html:

```
 <form action="post.php" method="post">

<input type="radio" name="Show" value="1">    <----- Click This<br><br>

Picture: <input type="text" name="Picture" class="span12" /><br><br>

Name: <input type="text" name="Name" class="span12" /><br><br>

Date:<br> <input type="text" name="Date" id="datepicker"><br><br>

Poster: <input type="text" name="Poster" class="span12" /><br><br>

Text: <textarea class="span12" name="comment" cols="45" rows="6" id="comment" class="bodytext"></textarea>

<input class="btn btn-large pull-right margin-top-15" type="submit" />
<input class="btn btn-small pull-left margin-top-15" type="reset" />

</form>
```

post.php:

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_select_db("DatabaseName", $con);
   function clean_string($value) {
   if(get_magic_quotes_gpc() ) {
        $value = stripslashes($value);
   }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($value);
```

}

```
    $Show = clean_string($_POST['Show']);
    $Picture = clean_string($_POST['Picture']);
    $Name = clean_string($_POST['Name']);
    $Date = clean_string($_POST['Date']);
    $Poster = clean_string($_POST['Poster']);
    $Comment = clean_string($_POST['comment']);

    $sql="INSERT INTO `posts` (`Show`, `Picture`, `Name`, `Date`, `Poster`, `Text`) VALUES ('$Show','$Picture','$Name','$Date','$Poster','$Comment')";
        if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
        {
         echo mysql_error() . "<br />$sql";      
        }
        echo "1 record added";
        mysql_close($con)
?>
```

Note:
Replace connection and database credential with yours.
Just try this code, no more comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use different word rather than show, 
or put it into single quates ['Show']